XDebug desde servidor Hostinger y con VSCode en local
Tengo un servidor compartido en Hostinger (no VPS) y he instalado la extensión de XDebug. Estoy utilizando VS Code como IDE con la extensión php debug.
Si entro en phpinfo(), puedo ver que XDebug está activo, pero solo en el modo desarrollador y no step debugging (debug). Como no puedo editar el archivo php.ini directamente, estoy realizando la configuración en el archivo .htaccess.
PHP Version 8.1.27 y XDebug Version 3.1.4
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers ✔ enabled
Coverage    ✘ disabled
GC Stats    ✘ disabled
Profiler    ✘ disabled
Step Debugger   ✘ disabled
Tracing ✘ disabled
El problema es que aunque ponga los breakpoints para que vaya parando e inicio el debug, no va parando. Además, en la configuración de XDebug -> Step Debugger  ✘ disabled
¿Alguna idea?
La configuración en .htaccess que tengo es:
# Configuración de XDebug para debugging remoto
php_value xdebug.mode develop,debug
php_value xdebug.start_with_request yes
php_value xdebug.client_host MI_IP_LOCAL
php_value xdebug.client_port 9003
php_value xdebug.idekey VSCODE
php_value xdebug.log MIPATHRAIZ/xdebug.log
php_value xdebug.log_level 1

En Visual studio code:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": true,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "pathMappings": {
                MIPath: "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

